# Unable to use "systemctl" in gitlab-ci.yml script

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci

This is my assignment.

```
Design an automation deployed with Gitlab pipelines to create load 
balanced simple nginx hosted on 1 or more virtual machines 
on AWS with the following assumption

1. CIDR retrieve from REST API https://FDQN/vend ip _return
{
"ip_address":"192.168.0.0"
"subnet_size"."/16"
}
2. Create subnets with size /24
3. Generate SSH key for VM credential

1. Take into consideration CSP Best Practices such as security and resiliency
2. Take into consideration coding scripting practices
3. Leverage on native cloud metrics logging for error handling
4. Use bash for the stack, Gitlab for the IAC pipeline
```

This is the script I am using for my gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy

  before_script:
  # Create .ssh dir to store private key
  - mkdir ~/.ssh
  - echo "$AWS_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  #Create Folder for nginx
  - mkdir -p /var/www/html
  - chmod 600 /var/www/html

  script:
    - echo "Start of script"
    - apt-get update -y
    - apt-get install -y nginx

    - systemctl start nginx
    - systemctl enable nginx
    - systemctl status nginx
```

But I keep receiving error 1,

```
Setting up nginx (1.18.0-6ubuntu14.4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.6) ...
$ systemctl start nginx
/usr/bin/bash: line 157: systemctl: command not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

does this issue lie with the gitlab runner or is it the user permissions of the aws account which I am using?

Answer (score 1):

In GitLab CI/CD pipelines, direct access to **systemd** commands like `systemctl` is **restricted** due to the isolated nature of the CI environment.

So you should run services in background or use Docker containers.

Start service as background process:

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Start service as Docker image:

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: nginx:latest
  script:
    - nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Useful links:

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/05/05/running-systemd-within-docker-container
https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/09/13/running-systemd-in-a-non-privileged-container